# When wrapping a type with Rust's newtype, how can inner fields be exposed or themselves wrapped?

Tags: rust, field, wrapper, newtype

As a newcomer to Rust, it seems that one of the most useful parts of the language is the `struct`, in particular the fact that it has named *fields*. This seems pretty core to the language as a whole.

I wish to wrap a third-party type called `glam::f64::DVec4` as my own type, `Tuple`, such that I can control what functions are available on my type, but delegate to glam's other functions as needed. From what I can glean from examples and docs, the way to go is to use a *newtype*:

```rust
pub struct Tuple(glam::f64::DVec4);

impl Tuple {
    pub fn new(x: f64, y: f64, z: f64, w: f64) -> Self {
        Self(glam::f64::DVec4 {x, y, z, w})
    }
}

// Factory function for ease of construction without referencing the type directly:
pub fn tuple(x: f64, y: f64, z: f64, w: f64) -> Tuple {
     Tuple::new(x, y, z, w)
}
```

However, whereas previously I would have been able to access the inner type's fields directly with `.x` or `.y`, I seem to lose this when I wrap it (unless I use `Tuple.0.x` I suppose, which seems ugly to me, and doesn't let me rename them, or perhaps intercept access to these fields via a function in my own code).

So I'm looking for some kind of "property" support (as one might have in, say, Python), that allows new fields to be created on the newtype `Tuple`, with whatever names I wish, and then map these to the original type's fields `x`, `y`, etc.

So in the end I'd have something like this (this does not compile):

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn default_tuple() {
        let a = tuple(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
        assert_eq!(a.x, 1.0);
        assert_eq!(a.y, 2.0);
        assert_eq!(a.z, 3.0);
        assert_eq!(a.w, 4.0);
    }
```

Is this possible, or will I need to add some kind of trait that provides `x()`, `y()`, ... access functions instead, and then `assert_eq!(a.x(), 1.0)`?

If creating or retaining fields is not possible, this seems to make newtypes omit the most useful thing about Rust's struct types - the *named fields*. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can implement `Deref` and `DerefMut`.

Comment: @PeterHall that seems to me like the [deref polymorphism antipattern](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/anti_patterns/deref.html).

Comment: @jthulhu Yes, that's what I'm referring to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property syntax (`.0` or `.name`) is only for actual properties of a struct. While it's somewhat restrictive, it does offer simplicity: if you see it, you know there is only one thing it can mean.

Compared to other languages, it's relatively uncommon in rust to use property names for access. The main reason why rust allows defining methods with the same name as properties is to allow you to make getter methods for your properties, which is what you will find on most structs in the rust ecosystem. These would usually be methods on your type and not in traits. If you need those fields for a trait, then the trait implementation should call the type-specific methods.

You can also implement `AsRef<DVec4>` and `AsMut<DVec4>`, which will make it easier for your code to be generic over `Tuple` and `DVec4`. You can also implement the comparison traits like `PartialEq` and conversion traits like `From` to make it easier to use `Tuple` and `DVec4` around each other.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then implementing functions like `Tuple::x(&self) -> f64 { self.0.x }` is idiomatic for not just wrapped types (newtypes) but for *all* types? So direct field access should be (typically) avoided in public interfaces, and used only within private implementation?

Comment: No, I would not go that far. Boilerplate accessor methods are not idiomatic, and Rust is not as enamored with encapsulation as traditional OO languages are. There is not really a blanket rule to either allow OR avoid direct field access. Is your type a plain bag of data with an obvious set of fields, or is it a abstract interface with black box internals? Where your types fall on this spectrum will inform the level of encapsulation they warrant.

Comment: @davidA If you have public members, you don't need getter methods, but when public members don't offer the functionality you want (like reserving the ability to change the internal representation without breaking API, or flattening nested structure, which is going on here), getter methods will be easily understood by other rust programmers.

Comment: @drewtato ok - however it seems there's no way (without `Deref`?) to _add_ public fields back into my newtype, so wrapping an existing type in a newtype, in effect to create a facade, seems to limit me to member functions (getters).

Comment: My earlier comment (within a minute of this one)  is intended for @JohnKugelman also.

Comment: @davidA Yep, your understanding is correct.

Comment: @davidA however note that `Deref` should be reserved for pointer-like types; it should not be used to mimic inheritance of OO languages. The reason for this is explained in the [antipattern book](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/anti_patterns/deref.html).